# How to get specific error message from SourceBuffer

Tags: html, media-source

I have an HTML5 video with a `MediaSource` for its source. When I call `SourceBuffer.appendBuffer()` the SourceBuffer throws an error.

I'm able to detect when this error is thrown like so:

```
sourceBuffer.addEventListener("error", function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

However the "arguments" in this case contain an `ErrorEvent` with no meaningful message or data. Just a reference to the SourceBuffer that failed.

I need to figure out ***why*** it failed, so I can fix it.

Comment: video/audio.error also holds information when a sourcebuffer error occurs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the most frustrating parts about MSE... it's really difficult to debug.  I think the issue is that the errors have to be standardized from browser to browser.  Since there's a lot of

If you're using Chrome, the best place to look is `chrome://media-internals`.

**As of Chrome 91** the media-internals pane is removed. Instead. go to

DevTools / hamburger menu (=== Customize and Control DevTools) / More Tools ▶ / Media

Then you'll have a Media tab on DevTools.

Comment: Using `chrome://media-internals` I was able to get **an** error message, but not a very helpful one. I'll make a new question and see if someone can help me diagnose further.

Comment: @stevendesu Such is life with MSE.  :-)  Good luck!